# Moving mail from 10.6 to 10.8... new computer

Tags: macos, email, contacts

I'm setting up a new computer and wanted to get my email contacts from 10.6.8 to 10.8.5 in Apple mail. I exported the mailboxes and I set up the accounts already... but no contacts show up when emailing. I tried copying the plist, but doesn't do anything. Will I have to copy the whole mail folder? I didn't want to muck this up since I already imported the mailboxes and set up the accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about the people that appear because they're previous recipients…

[image: Previous Recipients]

You can move these people by selection them from the Previous Recipients list (Window → Previous Recipients) then Add to Contacts.

Comment: I don't have anything saved in contacts... it's the mail addresses that pop up when emailing from apple mail for years?

Comment: Hmmmm... didn't realize that. So then I need to export contacts from old machine reimport to "contact" on new machine? Then they'll show up in mail???

Comment: @dhrose Yep, that'll do it. I've tried to find the preference file that holds the Previous Recipients, but I can't find it. Either way, the Add to Contacts method would still work.